# I want to fetch the data of child node from XML using C# Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

im trying to get child node data using c# Linq and i successfully fetch the data but not perfect string im getting data 
eg `"<value>data</value>"` like this but i want data eg: `"data"`

**this my code to fetch the data**

```
        var format = from data in xml.Descendants("Insurance")
                     select new
                     {

                         Policy = data.Element("CoreDetails").Elements("ReferenceColumn")
                                             .Elements("value")
                                             .Select(x =>x.ToString())
                                             .ToList()

                     };
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Insurance>
  <CoreDetails>
      <ReferenceColumn type="Array">
          <value>Policy number</value>
          <value>Address 1</value>
          <value>Buidling Prem</value>
      </ReferenceColumn> 
  </CoreDetails>
</Insurance>
```

Comment: Don't use `x.ToString()`, use `(string) x` or `x.Value`.

Comment: yeah thnx it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `InnerText` or `Value`:

```
var format = from data in xml.Descendants("Insurance")
             select new
             {    
                 Policy = data.Element("CoreDetails").Elements("ReferenceColumn")
                       .Elements("value")
                       .Select(x =>x.InnerText) //.Select(x =>x.Value)
                       .ToList()
             };
```